# Validity property not being set when input value is set by javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am using vue.js to build my UI and I am using the html DOM property validity along with rules on my input tags(pattern, minLength, maxLength etc.) It seems like the validity property only gets set if I edit the text box manually. If I programatically assign an invalid value to my variable bound to the input tag with v-model, the validity property is not working as expected. It only works if I actually enter something into the input. I have tried programatically firing off keyup and change events for the input box to try and get it to validate and it is not working. Has anyone encountered this before? I know there are good plugins for validating with vuejs but I would prefer to use the built in HTML5 functionality.

If you want to see code samples reply in comments.

Comment: Have you tried explicitly triggering the validity check after setting a new value via script? https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-cva-checkvalidity

Comment: yes, it does not work. It returns true if  the input field remains untouched by user interaction (only vuejs changing its value)

Comment: Well then that must have to do with how Vue sets the "value", because in vanilla JS setting `element.value` makes constraint validation do it's job fine, without even any need to explicitly trigger it. Could come down to the old attribute vs property thing I suppose.

Comment: @CBroe so you thinking this should work? this.$refs.someInputElement.value = this.$refs.someInputElement.value

Comment: Setting the current value again? What's that supposed to achieve? And why would that require to run constraint validation now? The field is still either valid or invalid, as it was before.